# Duplication Id creation Error Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, exception, on-duplicate-key

I am using pentaho data integration tool to populate Mongodb collection from a SQL Server database. There are no indexes defined in the mongodb collection.The job is getting failed because of the creation of duplicate ids in the collection.

I would want to know in which scenario it could cause the issue. Any advise would be really helpful.

```
occurred during write: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Write operation to server /myhost:27017 failed on database transactions

    ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : An error     occurred during write: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey:
   { "serverUsed" : "/myhost:27017" , "connectionId" : 186 , "err" :
   "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error
   index: transactions.datacollection.$_id_  dup key: { :
   ObjectId('534fe5644503839b0f6d47a2') }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 ,
   "ok" : 1.0} 

ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy)
   : An error occurred during write:
   com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" :
   "/myhost:27017" , "connectionId" : 186 , "err" : "insertDocument ::
   caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:
   transactions.datacollection.$_id_  dup key: { :
   ObjectId('534fe5644503839b0f6d47a2') }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 ,
   "ok" : 1.0}  

   ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy)
   : An error occurred during write: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network:
   Write operation to server /myhost:27017 failed on database
   transactions

   MongoDB Output.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from
   2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : An error occurred during write:
   com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" :
   "/myhost:27017" , "connectionId" : 187 , "err" : "insertDocument ::
   caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:
   transactions.datacollection.$_id_  dup key: { :
   ObjectId('534fe5644503839b0f6d47a2') }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 ,
   "ok" : 1.0}

   ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Unexpected   error ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from
   2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) :
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, _id fied is automatically added by mongodb (driver or daemon) if you do not provide one. _id is indexed with the attribute unique. see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/.

If the driver is taking care of the stuff as the java driver does (at least for the latest version), and you do something like the following

```
    MongoClient c =  new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://somehost"));
    DB db = c.getDB("someDB");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("someCollection");
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("field1", "value1");

    coll.insert(obj);

    obj.removeField("field1");
    obj.append("field1", "value2");
    coll.insert(obj);
    //maybe in a loop
```

You are into trouble, because the first time you call insert, _id is not generated, and later, there is no need to regenerate it. You are using the same _id all the time. You can create a new basicDBObject of remove the field _id to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a simulation application that generates random data and inserting into MongoDB, I faced the same trouble and if that's helpful; each time you call insert operation for a BasicDBObject, at the end of the function you would call "clear()" operation as well.